# Correct PEX sizing for dedicated recirculation line between fixtures

Tags: plumbing, pump, pex

I plan on using the TACO 600e3 recirc pump. My dedicated recirculation line is slightly over 100'. The TACO Instruction Sheet (https://www.tacocomfort.com/documents/FileLibrary/006e3_iSheet_102-533.pdf) recommends using the low setting, based on my length at 3/4" with a 1/2" return.

Per my sizing chart 3/4" will provide for up to 14 TFU and 1/2" will cover up to 4 TFU. I originally planned on using a 1/2" for the 40' return from the KITCHEN SINK/DISHWASHER to the WH.
If I'm not mistaken, can't I step down to 1/2" immediately after the BATH/SHOWER COMBO since the two remaining fixtures combined are under 4 TFU?

Also, since all my stub-outs for the WH are 3/4" will using a 1/2" to 3/4" adapter cause any issues? Can't see any other way to do this.

DESIGN:

- WH > BATH/SHOWER COMBO (4 TFU) 20'
- BATH/SHOWER COMBO > BATHROOM LAV (1 TFU) 20'
- BATHROOM LAV > KITCHEN SINK/DISHWASHER 26'
- KITCHEN SINK/DISHWASHER > WH 40'

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Where I live (western US) the return line on *all* our home hot water circulation systems use 1/2" pipe. This is plenty to service the small circ. pump.

As far as feeding your kitchen sink and DW- I personally would run 3/4" to them and then split to 1/2" for each fixture.  1/2" *might* be OK- I would rather error on the side of making sure I had enough volume to service both fixtures rather than possibly cutting that short. Also, this is how my local plumbers would do it when running the plumbing for a new house.

Comment: 1/2" each? The kitchen sink and dishwasher both use 3/8" lines from the stub out.

Comment: The service to the angle stop (shut off valve) is always 1/2" here- and yes, usually the supply to each fixture (the flex line from the angle stop) is 3/8". I am just stating what is typically done here where I am.